# What is use case for stealth_options in Django?

Tags: django

according to [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/2.0/):

> For custom management commands that use options not created using
> parser.add_argument(), add a stealth_options attribute on the command:
>
> ```
> class MyCommand(BaseCommand):
>     stealth_options = ('option_name', ...)
> ```

but why not just add these options to parser.add_argument()? Is there any profit to use stealth_options?

Answer (score 2):

Mainly for testing purpose IMO, check this code snippet taken from this [example](https://github.com/django/django/blob/798835112d81b852efaae0e067af389c733cd1b3/tests/inspectdb/tests.py).

```
 def inspectdb_tables_only(table_name):
    """
    Limit introspection to tables created for models of this app.
    Some databases such as Oracle are extremely slow at introspection.
    """
    return table_name.startswith('inspectdb_')


class InspectDBTestCase(TestCase):
    unique_re = re.compile(r'.*unique_together = \((.+),\).*')

    def test_stealth_table_name_filter_option(self):
        out = StringIO()
        call_command('inspectdb', table_name_filter=inspectdb_tables_only, stdout=out)
        error_message = "inspectdb has examined a table that should have been filtered out."
        self.assertNotIn("class DjangoContentType(models.Model):", out.getvalue(), msg=error_message)
```

Now we can use `stealth_options` to simplify the process of **bypassing call_command() check** and refine our test method **while hiding these *options* from the exposed command API**.

> call_command() now validates that the argument parser of the command
> being called defines all of the options passed to call_command().

Comment: I think we used it in similar situation. However, we still can bypass that check with parser.add_argument. `stealth_options` seems to be a simpler/shorter way to do that.